# Coordinate system rotation 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, rotations

I have two different coordinate systems, $A$ and $B$, with the same origin but rotated. I know that the axes of system $B$ have the following coordinates in system $A$.
$$
\begin{align}
x_B &= (-0.021, -0.723,  0.689)\\
y_B &= (-0.070, 0.689, 0.721)\\
z_B &= (-0.997, -0.033, -0.066)
\end{align}
$$

I also have a vector $C$ of length $3$ in the $y_A$- direction. Now, I'm wondering what are the coordinates of $C$ in the $B$ coordinate system. At first, I was thinking that I could simply use the transformation

x$_C$ = 3*0.723

y$_C$ = 3*0.689

z$_C$ = 3*0.021

But I don't think that's correct. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This approach may be helpful.  Define $B$ to be the matrix formed from the vectors of the system-B axes relative to system-A:

$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
−0.021 & −0.070 & −0.997 \\
−0.723 & 0.689 & −0.033 \\
0.689 & 0.721 & −0.066 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This matrix will transform coordinates from system-B to system-A via:

$$
\mathbf{x}_{A}=B\mathbf{x}_{B}
$$

where $\mathbf{x}_{A}$ are the coordinates in system-A and $\mathbf{x}_{B}$ are the coordinates in system-B.

To determine a coordinate tranformation from system-A to system-B, one then needs the inverse of $B$:

$$
B^{-1}\mathbf{x}_{A}=\mathbf{x}_{B}
$$

$$
B^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.0217157 & -0.724614 & 0.690345 \\
-0.0705677 & 0.68942 & 0.72129 \\
-0.997597 & -0.0331419 & -0.0651831 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, this can be multiplied by the vector in the system-A:

$$
\mathbf{x}_{B}=B^{-1}\mathbf{x}_{A}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.0217157 & -0.724614 & 0.690345 \\
-0.0705677 & 0.68942 & 0.72129 \\
-0.997597 & -0.0331419 & -0.0651831 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
3 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\mathbf{x}_{B}=B^{-1}\mathbf{x}_{A}=
3
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.724614 \\
0.68942 \\
-0.0331419 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect explanation.

Comment: Very helpful indeed! Thanks a lot!